# yum install mcrypt on AWS linux (centos)

Tags: php

I cant seem to install `mcrypt` on my new linux box with PHP 5.4 
I have tried `sudo yum install php-mcrypt`, `sudo yum install php-mcrypt.x86_64`

result:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.28-1.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.28-1.5.amzn1 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.28-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.28-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.28-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-9.1.2.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.4.2-18.4.8.2.21.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.28-1.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php54-common-5.4.30-1.56.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.4.30-1.56.amzn1
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php54-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.28-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

inside php.ini i've added `mcrypt.so`, but this didnt do anything
so then i took that off and created `/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini` and added `extension=mcrypt.so`

Any help please
thank you

Comment: this belongs on serverfault.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chances are the package is named `php54-mcrypt` instead of `php-mcrypt` if you have existing packages named like `php54-common`.

Answer (score 19):

you can use:

```
sudo yum install php56-mcrypt
sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove all php5.3 associated packages, including httpd, because php5.4>= works with httpd24.  After unistalling all these packages, check that all your packages are compatible with php 5.4.

This code might allow you removing httpd in order to reinstall httpd24:
`sudo yum erase httpd httpd-tools apr apr-util`

Check this link that works for php 5.5 and might help you installing php5.4
[installing php.5.5 with mcrypt on AWS Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392716/installing-php-5-5-with-mcrypt-on-aws-linux/28330951#28330951)

Answer (score 0):

sudo yum install php56-mcrypt

sudo service httpd restart

worked wery well for me